# How to add app/widget shortcuts to launcher using MonkeyDevice

Tags: android

Using monkeyrunner I need to simulate creation of application/widget shortcut on launcher from apps screen.

Now from Apps screen (Apps/Widgets tab) I can simulate long keypress and selection of app with

> device.touch(x1, y1, MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
>
> time.sleep(2)

After execution of these two, I see the device goes to launcher screen where shortcut can be dragged to desired position.

However if I add the following (after previous instructions 1 and 2) to simulate drag and drop. Nothing happens:

> device.drag((x1, y1), (x2, y2), 3, 10)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.